# An internal server error has occurred Error ID: 99989560-2011 (1597204713)

Tags: lightning, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, gack

We have developed a hybrid application using Salesforce MobileSDK 5.3. Salesforce is integral part of the application.

Our app do support Salesforce lightning plugins and render components using lighting into the app.

Since Salesforce Sandbox has been updated with winter 19, app is unable to load lightning component. Here is error which app recieves when tries to load lightning app.

> **An internal server error has occurred** 
>   An error has occurred while processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the error, please contact Salesforce Support. Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience. 
>  Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using salesforce.com! 
> Error ID: 99989560-2011 (1597204713)

**Please note** - Lightning components loads fine on orgs not having Winter 19 update it looks like something has changed recently which cause this breakdown

Here is code to load lightning plugin.

```
$Lightning.use("c:MyLightningApp.app", function () {
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:MyLightningComponent", {},
               "myLightningDiv",
                function (cmp) {
                    console.log("Component created!");
                    console.log(cmp);
                }
            );
        }, ""https://xxx-mydomainname.lightning.force.com" ", "Bearer " +  "myoauth-access-token");
```

Any idea why this happening?

Any help? It's quite critical, we have client release and currently unable to release due to this error.

Let me know if you need any other information.

Regards,
Manish Kumar

Comment: This may have been impacted because of the upgrade. And that you have run into a [**gack**](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html), and the only place to get help is Salesforce Support.

Comment: Is there anything I can try on?